# Using NSURLConnecion delegates with NSURLConnection +sendAsynchronousRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

How does one use NSURLConnection delegate callbacks when using the

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                      queue:(NSOperationQueue*) queue
          completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))
```

method?

I would like to be able to access the caching delegate callback on the queue handling the completion block.

Comment: I think that the cache policy depends on how you've set up your URL request.Are you asking this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't. You need to use the NSURLConnection method, initWithRequest:delegate:, instead of sendAsynchronousRequest, to use the delegate call back methods.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to make sense. sendAsynchronousRequest is a class method of NSURLConnection.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I updated my. answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use it like this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kURL];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL      :   url
                                                        cachePolicy     :   NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                        timeoutInterval :   30];
NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"param=%d",digits];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]  
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *taxiData, NSError *error) {

 //Snippet - Do sth. (block)

}
```

Hope this help.

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't read your question clearly. +sendAsynchronousRequest did not require delegates method.

EDIT2: or, maybe, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270447/how-to-use-sendasynchronousrequestqueuecompletionhandler) will help you

Answer (score 0):

In order to use delegate methods with `NSURLConnection` you need to instantiate a `NSURLConnection` variable.  Since

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                  queue:(NSOperationQueue*) queue
      completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))
```

is a superclass method you can't use it.