# Application freezes when sending a post request to the server

Tags: ios, objective-c, foundation

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@",_benimEmail]; 
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]; 
[request setURL:[NSURLURLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/iphone/msg.php"]]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error; NSURLResponse *response; 
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; 
NSString *veri = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSLog(@"%@",veri);
```

This code above is run on a button click, and it will query a web service.

Now, when I click on the button, the application freezes for a while. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because you are using sendSynchronousRequest.

Use sendAsynchronousRequest instead.

Comment: can you give me an example pls? Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270447/how-to-use-sendasynchronousrequestqueuecompletionhandler

Answer (score 0):

You are performing blocking calls on UI thread and that is causing the freeze.

You could use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) (not maintained but works fine) class and use their method to do async network call

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

or you can look into the more superior [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) library

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection is provided by apple is more recommended way of placing URL request. Below I explained a code in brief with the name of delegate methods of request.It will also prevent to block the UI of app.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and handle its response and errors using its delegate methods.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

You can find implementation of NSURLConnection

[NSURLConnectionDocs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html/%22NSURLConnectionDocs%22)